# EF4 Strip table prefixes on import

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am attempting to have table names automatically renamed to strip off a leading prefix in EF4.  I know it can be done in the GUI, however, my company created the DB schema in Visio and use that to create the DB creation script in SQL.  We do this often, and sometimes have a lot of tables, so using the GUI is not an ideal solution.

Is there a way to modify the properties on the .edmx file to strip off a defined prefix from the DB table so the Entity class is how we desire it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution we came up with was to make a new console application that did the low level work of renaming everything in the edmx file; the application can be added to the tools menu of Visual Studio (add external tool) with 'arguments' = $(ItemPath), 'initial directory' = $(ItemDir), 'prompt for arguments' = true and 'use output window' = true, then can be executed with the EDMX file selected. In our case, we needed to strip underscores and transform the names to camel case (interpreting the underscore as a word separator), in addition to stripping the prefix.

I'll omit the rest of the code (like the Transform.Standard method, error handling and the stripping of additional parameters) because it's too badly written to share and it's too late at night for refactoring :P; but it's easy enough to interpret the rest of the arguments after the first as strings to be stripped from names and so on - this main code is only about the modifications needed on the EDMX file. In case you use this as an External Tool from VS, you can specify the rest of the strings after $(ItemPath) in 'arguments'.

Please note this wasn't tested extensively, and there may be additional information in other EDMX files that we failed to account for (but I doubt it); also, I got part of the code from somewhere else on the net but failed to write down where exactly, so sorry! Credit should have been given accordingly. Also, naturally this would have been much better as an extension for VS2010, but I simply did not have the time to do it - if you do link it somewhere and I'll use that instead ;)

```
if (_args.Count < 1) return;

string file = _args.First();
if (!File.Exists(file))
{
    wait("Could not find specified file.");
    return;
}
if (Path.GetExtension(file) != ".edmx")
{
    wait("This works only on EDMX files.");
    return;
}

//processing:

Console.WriteLine("Creating backup: " + Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".bak"));
File.Copy(file, Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".bak"), true);

Console.WriteLine("Reading target document...");

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);

const string CSDLNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm";
const string MSLNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs";
const string DiagramNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx";

XElement csdl = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Schema", CSDLNamespace)).First();
XElement msl = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Mapping", MSLNamespace)).First();
XElement designerDiagram = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Diagram", DiagramNamespace)).First();

//modifications for renaming everything, not just table names:

string[] CSDLpaths = new string[] 
{
    "EntityContainer/EntitySet.Name",
    "EntityContainer/EntitySet.EntityType",
    "EntityContainer/AssociationSet/End.EntitySet",
    "EntityType.Name",
    "EntityType/Key/PropertyRef/Name",
    "EntityType/Property.Name",
    "EntityType/NavigationProperty.Name",
    "Association/End.Type",
    "Association//PropertyRef.Name",

};

#region CSDL2

Console.WriteLine("Modifying CSDL...");
Console.WriteLine(" - modifying entity sets...");

foreach (var entitySet in csdl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainer", CSDLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("EntitySet", CSDLNamespace)))
{
    entitySet.Attribute("Name").Value = Transform.Standard(entitySet.Attribute("Name").Value);
    entitySet.Attribute("EntityType").Value = Transform.Standard(entitySet.Attribute("EntityType").Value);
}

Console.WriteLine(" - modifying association sets...");
foreach (var associationSet in csdl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainer", CSDLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("AssociationSet", CSDLNamespace)))
{
    foreach (var end in associationSet.Elements(XName.Get("End", CSDLNamespace)))
    {
        end.Attribute("EntitySet").Value = Transform.Standard(end.Attribute("EntitySet").Value);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(" - modifying entity types...");
foreach (var entityType in csdl.Elements(XName.Get("EntityType", CSDLNamespace)))
{
    entityType.Attribute("Name").Value = Transform.Standard(entityType.Attribute("Name").Value);

    foreach (var key in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("Key", CSDLNamespace)))
    {
        foreach (var propertyRef in key.Elements(XName.Get("PropertyRef", CSDLNamespace)))
        {
            propertyRef.Attribute("Name").Value = Transform.Standard(propertyRef.Attribute("Name").Value);
        }
    }

    foreach (var property in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("Property", CSDLNamespace)))
    {
        property.Attribute("Name").Value = Transform.Standard(property.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }

    foreach (var navigationProperty in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("NavigationProperty", CSDLNamespace)))
    {
        navigationProperty.Attribute("Name").Value = Transform.Standard(navigationProperty.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }

}

Console.WriteLine(" - modifying associations...");
foreach (var association in csdl.Elements(XName.Get("Association", CSDLNamespace)))
{
    foreach (var end in association.Elements(XName.Get("End", CSDLNamespace)))
    {
        end.Attribute("Type").Value = Transform.Standard(end.Attribute("Type").Value);
    }
    foreach (var propref in association.Descendants(XName.Get("PropertyRef", CSDLNamespace)))
    {
        //propertyrefs are contained in constraints
        propref.Attribute("Name").Value = Transform.Standard(propref.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }
}

#endregion

#region MSL2

Console.WriteLine("Modifying MSL...");
Console.WriteLine(" - modifying entity set mappings...");

foreach (var entitySetMapping in msl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainerMapping", MSLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("EntitySetMapping", MSLNamespace)))
{
    entitySetMapping.Attribute("Name").Value = Transform.Standard(entitySetMapping.Attribute("Name").Value);

    foreach (var entityTypeMapping in entitySetMapping.Elements(XName.Get("EntityTypeMapping", MSLNamespace)))
    {
        entityTypeMapping.Attribute("TypeName").Value = Transform.Standard(entityTypeMapping.Attribute("TypeName").Value);
        foreach
        (var scalarProperty in
        (entityTypeMapping.Element(XName.Get("MappingFragment", MSLNamespace))).Elements(XName.Get("ScalarProperty", MSLNamespace))
        )
        {
            scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value = Transform.Standard(scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(" - modifying association set mappings...");

foreach (var associationSetMapping in msl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainerMapping", MSLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("AssociationSetMapping", MSLNamespace)))
{
    foreach (var endProperty in associationSetMapping.Elements(XName.Get("EndProperty", MSLNamespace)))
    {
        foreach (var scalarProperty in endProperty.Elements(XName.Get("ScalarProperty", MSLNamespace)))
        {
            scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value = Transform.Standard(scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value);
        }
    }
}
#endregion


#region Designer

Console.WriteLine("Modifying designer content...");
foreach (var item in designerDiagram.Elements(XName.Get("EntityTypeShape", DiagramNamespace)))
{
    item.Attribute("EntityType").Value = Transform.Standard(item.Attribute("EntityType").Value);
}

#endregion

Console.WriteLine("Writing result...");

using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(args[0], Encoding.Default))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xdoc.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Edit: adding the Transform class used by the code above. Also, please note that this works for Entity Framework 4.0 - later versions might have slightly different EDMX structure (I'm not sure) so the code might need to be modified to account for that.

```
public class Transform
{
    public static string Standard(string initial, IEnumerable<string> eliminations = null)
    {
        Regex re = new Regex(@"(\w+)(\W*?)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        Regex camelSplit = new Regex(@"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        return re.Replace(initial, new MatchEvaluator((Match m) =>
        {
            string name = m.Groups[1].Value;
            var parts = name.Split('_').AsEnumerable();
            if (parts.Count() == 1 && IsMixedCase(name))
            {
                string result = string.Concat(camelSplit.Split(name).Except(eliminations, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                return result + m.Groups[2];
            }
            else
            {
                parts = parts.Select(s => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLower()));
                parts = parts.Except(eliminations, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                return string.Concat(parts) + m.Groups[2];
            }
        }));
    }

    public static bool IsMixedCase(string name)
    {
        int lower = 0, total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsLower(name, i)) lower++;
            if (char.IsLetter(name, i)) total++;
        }
        return lower != 0 && lower != total;
    }

}
```

Now you could write a little bit more code in the Main method that could take the arguments (except the first one which will be the name of the file) and pass them onward to the `eliminations` parameter; these could be strings that need to be erased from the names, in my case the prefixes. You can then specify these strings from the visual studio tools interface when invoking the tool. Or I suppose you can just hardcode them if you don't care that much about reusing the tool :)

Comment: sorry for the long delay in the acceptance! one of my co-workers discovered a working solution, and since I no longer work at that company, I completely forget what he discovered.  But your answer is good and works; so like you said: give credit where it's due!

Comment: @Alex I am facing the same issue. I just need some clarification in your solution... i have created a console application.. where should i add the above code u mentioned? then how to execute it...Am completely new to this... Please help me out

Comment: @Xavier - simply add it in the Main method. I'll edit the answer to include the missing code. Then just make sure it compiles (it was long ago but I can probably help if something doesn't work) and place the executable somewhere and set up the tools in Visual Studio to add a 'shortcut' to it as I described - of course you can also run it manually from a console if you prefer.

Comment: @AlexPaven What is that executable? Should i create an exe for the console application?

Comment: @Xavier well yes, I mean that will be the tool you're creating to help you do the transform; it's not very well integrated but it's a lot simpler than creating say a VS extension.

Comment: @AlexPaven Ok... I have done as you mentioned. How to run it along with the edmx file..How will it change the class names which is already been created..

Comment: The first paragraph of my answer shows you how to do it using the Tools - External tools - Add option of Visual Studio. If it's not clear I'll edit it...

Comment: @AlexPaven Ya that's clear... I have done all those. After doing all those the newtool appears in the tools menu. Just clicking that and installing it will give me the required solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25134/discussion-between-alex-paven-and-xavier)

Comment: @AlexPaven I am unable to connect to chat.. Please continue  via comment

Comment: Select the file in solution explorer, then click on the tool in the tools menu. That will invoke the executable, passing it the file name as the first argument. (StackOverflow recommends avoiding long comment threads, that's why I suggested chat).

Comment: @AlexPaven Its invoking the executable.. In the Arguments tab it is already filled with the value "$(ItemPath)"... Should i change that to the edmx file name or what is that file name supposed to be..

Am really sorry Alex as i am completely new i am troubling with lots of questions.. Please pardon me..

Comment: @Xavier please read my replies carefully: select the file in solution explorer then run the tool. That will automatically transform $(ItemPath) into the name of the EDMX and pass it on to the console application.

Comment: @AlexPaven Done that... It prompted me to install... just installed it.. But still the class names remains the same..:(

Comment: Look I'm sorry but I don't know what went wrong, you'll need to do some investigation by yourself. Add some tracing code to the console application or something...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about any build in feature for stripping table prefixes but you can open .edmx file as XML (use Open With in VS) and use simple replacing to replace prefix with nothing.