# EF error when executing a SQL query where the column name doesn't match the return type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF model based on my database. Because the creator of the database gave the column the same name as the table, EF renamed the it and appended a 1 to it.

So I have table `Cat` with column `Cat1`.

When I run sql on the context with type Cat, it returns columns including the column `Cat`. Because there is no column `Cat` on my EF model, it throws an exception trying to map it.

Is there a fix for this? Unfortunately the query/method is generic so I must do `select * from`.

Comment: Have you tried this? Using data annotations to use 'Cat' as the Column Name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554888/change-table-and-column-name-mappings-entity-framework-v4-3

Comment: Woah I have not, that's some pretty impressive stuff! I'll give it a shot, thanks