# EF7 Scaffold Existing DB With Column Names = Table Names

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am currently playing around with ASP.net 5 / EF 7 and at this point trying to scaffold my existing DB (~1200 Tables).

Command used: `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "<connstring>" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outputDir Models -a;`

Basically it works as intended - but unfortunately there are several Tables (97) which contain a column with the same name as the table, causing a lot of "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type" errors.

I know that I can change the Classnames manually, that would work but it is a lot of (unnecessary) work + given DB Changes in the future I would have to repeat that step on each new scaffolding.

Dnx ef dbcontext help does not give any hints.

Anyone found an easy workaround yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know bug in RC1, and has been fixed in RC2 and latest daily builds: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/3712

Comment: Rename your columns?

Comment: still not out :-(

in the meantime you can do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10554917/16940

Comment: RC2 is out - what do you mean "still not out" ?

Comment: How do I find it on nuget? Rc1 is the latest i see.

Comment: Name change! Look for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: Thx. Why can't they put deprecation notices on these old packages 

Comment: But a nice link to the new package would be very useful. Already ran into this before. It just makes updating to newer stuff much more frustrating than it ought to be

Comment: for anyone else getting confused by this here's the announcement of the changes : https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144

Comment: also also here https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html